# Angular 2+ unbind properties in ngIf

Tags: angular

I have a form with a datepicker. On certain days of data entry, additional fields will be shown. For instance

`<div *ngIf="ticketDate.getDay() === 0"`

Inside of this div, I am binding to some optional properties on my model.  However, if the user changes the date picker to a different date after entering data, the contents of the div are no longer visible but the properties remain set on my model.

Is there an idiomatic way to unbind properties that are bound inside an `*ngIf` when it is false?

Comment: Can we see how the optional properties are defined and bound?

Comment: @ConnorsFan I'm just using [(ngModel)] on inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set a template reference variable `#myDiv` on the `div` element:

```
<div #myDiv *ngIf="ticketDate.getDay() === 0">
```

and monitor the presence of the element with `ViewChildren` and the `QueryList.changes` event. The model properties could be reset when the `div` is removed from the DOM:

```
@ViewChildren("myDiv") myDivList: QueryList<ElementRef>;

value1: string;
value2: string;
value3: string;

constructor(private changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.myDivList.changes.subscribe((list) => {
    if (!list.length) {
      this.value1 = undefined;
      this.value2 = undefined;
      this.value3 = undefined;
      this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
  });
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cpapw5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) for a demo. The method `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges` is called to prevent an Angular exception.

Comment: I was hoping for a solution that didn't require explicitly changing the fields, but it appears there's no baked in way for that.  Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 1):

You say that you are using a form, apparently a template driven form if you are using `ngModel`. You could just not use `[(ngModel)]` and instead use `ngModel`. Then there is no need to reset values. If the part of template is not visible, it will not be included in the form at all. If that is a suitable option, I suggest the following (demo is modified version of ConnorsFan's stackblitz):

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(myForm.value)">
  <div *ngIf="ticketDate.getDay() === 0">
    Value1: <input ngModel name="value1">
    Value2: <input ngModel name="value2">
  </div>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Name (all) the form fields like you want, and in the structure you want, so that when you submit your form, the form object corresponds to the model you want. So the above form values submitted would be (if condition is true):

```ts
{
  "value1": "some value",
  "value2": "some value"
}
```

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sxwbsd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

*PS: if you need reference to the form in your ts file at some point you can use `ViewChild` as seen in the demo.*